# What is the time complexity of the addFirst(e) and the removeFirst() methods

Tags: java, time-complexity

I am studying for an exam and somewhat understand time complexity with Big Oh notation. I was given this as an example of what they will be asking and curious what your thoughts are. I am not sure whether these are linear O(n) or what. If you could help me out, some of these complexity problems confuse me a bit. Thank you in advance.

```
public E removeFirst() {
      if (size == 0) {
        return null;
      }
      else {
        Node<E> temp = head;
        head = head.next;
        size--;
        if (head == null) {
          tail = null;
        }
        return temp.element;
}
}


    public void addFirst(E e) {
      Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e); 
      newNode.next = head; 
      head = newNode; 
      size++; 

      if (tail == null) 
        tail = head;
}
```

Comment: Complexity O(n) can appear if you have cycle or recursion. As you see, your methods has predictible amount of operations and this amount doesn't depend on lenght of you list. That's why the complexity is O(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big O notation roughly means the maximum number of times your code needs to be executed in the worst case, since in both of your functions it returns the result with only one iteration in any case thus the worst case complexity of both your functions is O(1) i.e. constant time.